# trying to work out how to use Lightbox JS

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I am trying to use LightBox JS (I have checked the modal box in bootstrap but it seems to have a structure that I can not adapt to the customer requirement), I thing lightbox JS is the one it might work better, but if anyone things there is anyone better for what I need... please, tell me! The customer needs a lightbox when the user clicks a button (actually is a span with an anchor tag), Then, in the same window, this lightbox needs to cover the whole document with a grey background with half opacity (to keep seeing the content of the main page), and then the lightBox has to look as a notebook (with holes in the left side.... grid page....) so definitely I need to be able to customize it. And then, inside the "notebook page" it needs to be a slider of images.

Trying with lightbox I am not getting any useful result;

this is my button:

```
<a href="#" rel="lightbox" data-toggle="lightbox"><span class="viewMorePs">SKETCH IDEAS</span></a>
```

I have read that they put href="#someurl" or href="someurl", that is my first doubt, what do I have to put in href if I want the lightbox in the same window?

And then.... Where am I supose to add the content for the lightbox????

So with my code so far. If I inspect the element, I see it creates a div with id lightBoxDetails, but where is it physically? Then, if I add to this #lightBoxDetails display: block !important appears this:

[image]

But I don't see how can I add my own content or how to manage it, and then, another question... if this lightBox is an ID...does it mean I can not have a lightbox for each button? (I have a container, with 3 buttons which all of them needs a different lightbox).

If anyone have use it successfully... please, get in touch!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Lightbox will always load on the page you are on.  It will prevent the default action of the link and then load the contents of the links href into the lightbox

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation for the Ligthbox library you are using? I belive there are different versions. Also, are you certain that you can load HTML in it? various lightbox libraries only let you load images. Let us know.